# What is Communications error: OS_xpc_error in Xcode 6?

Tags: xcode, swift

I got this error this morning and can't find a reasonable explanation:

```
Communications error: <OS_xpc_error: <error: 0x3b3c2614> { count = 1, contents =
    "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x3b3c286c> { length = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted" }
}>
```

I think this happen when I am taking a photo. I can show the complete snippet upon request. However, it's example code from a tutorial. It only showed up once, and there is not much explanation online either.

I have turned on breakpoint `at all exception` and symbolic breakpoint at `UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints`. But this error showed too without these breakpoints set.

Neither of the breakpoint invoked when this error showed up.

What is this?

Comment: Did you found the solution? i also got this error. But only once. I don't know the reason also what invoked this error.

Comment: It somehow fixes itself after rerun. If i run into it again i will answer this question.

Comment: Having the same issue. I get this even with the app sitting idle with a blank view. Is it a XCode error while running in debug mode?

Comment: I got this problem while changing orientations using the iOS simulator. I wasn't able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: i got same error, was when the simulator was left idle, my app is just a testing ground, just calls a webservice using a NSURLConnection. does basically nothing. maybe its a problem with the simulator

Comment: did you figure this out?  I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

*XPC* is Apple's inter-process communication (IPC) system. Some functionality (such as h.264 encoding/decoding, or interacting with camera hardware) is handled by a separate app - a daemon - that runs all the time in the background.

*Connection interrupted* means that the IPC connection was interrupted for some reason. Perhaps it took too long, perhaps the timing was just bad and the daemon or your app needed to urgently do something else.

It's probably not an error per se. When dealing with IPC, the daemon should be considered a black box, and your connection to it, somewhat flimsy. In this case you're talking to the daemon indirectly (via Apple's libraries), and it's likely they've designed it to work asynchronously and automatically recover from errors.

Comment: Is that why when i rerun it, it somehow fixes itself, i reckon?

Comment: Most likely. You typically don't have any direct interaction with XPC, and if there are persistent issues it could be a bug and you should ask on the Apple developer forums and/or file a bug report.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same Error.
My mistake was to load an URL of a specific gif (http://whyd.com/uCoverImg/bd1833e6afe5a8ae9c9aff4177d3f80d_960x.gif) with SDWebImage in a imageView

```
NSURL *url = NSURL urlFromString:@"image.gif"];
[myImageView sd_setImageWithURL:imageCoverUrl];
```

This crash isn't exist for all GIF pictures, I have to find the right rule

Comment: In my case, I didn't implement gif, it was just an issue with views' layout clash. But somehow it fixes itself, I can't replicate this error again.

Comment: This issue reproducible as when I upload 50+ images and fetching photos from document directory.

Comment: In my case I was loading a *very big* image by URL, causing a memory crash with no crash log. This gave me a hint.