# Breakpoint when run on device but not in Simulator in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, breakpoints

I run this app on the Simulator normally but when I tried it on an actual Device it crashes but unlike most breakpoints there was no message just a "Lost connection to Device" popup. It happens every time I run it on a device but never in the Simulator. It's not a problem with the connection wire.

I have a lot of code but here's the important stuff:

```
    print("Test-1")
            let imageView2 = uiview


            // Find the path where to

 save
        guard let myFilePath = createMyFilePath(forFileName: "Page1test.png") else {
            print("Cannot generate file path ☹️")
            exit(0)
        }

        // Use this to check in finder where your file is saved
        print(myFilePath)
        print("Test")

        // Transform the imageView in UIImage to save it
        let imageToSave = createImage(fromView: imageView2)

        // Get the image as data
        guard let imageToSaveAsData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageToSave) else {
            print("Cannot transform image to data ☹️")
            exit(1)
        }

        // Save to Disk!
        do{
            try imageToSaveAsData.writeToFile(myFilePath, options: .DataWritingAtomic)
        } catch {
            print("Error, cannot write to the location \(myFilePath)")
        }


        // Load from Disk!
        let loadedImageData = NSData(contentsOfFile: myFilePath)

        // Check the data is the same
        if loadedImageData == imageToSaveAsData {
            print("✌️")
        }

        // Have a look at the loaded image!
        var bob = UIImage(data: loadedImageData!)

        imageviewloaded.image = bob


        //Page 2

        let imageViewtest = uiview2


        // Find the path where to save
        guard let myFilePathtest = createMyFilePath(forFileName: "Page2test.png") else {
            print("Cannot generate file path ☹️")
            exit(0)
        }

        // Use this to check in finder where your file is saved
        print(myFilePathtest)

        // Transform the imageView in UIImage to save it
        let imageToSavetest = createImage(fromView: imageViewtest)

        // Get the image as data
        guard let imageToSaveAsDatatest = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageToSavetest) else {
            print("Cannot transform image to data ☹️")
            exit(1)
        }

        // Save to Disk!
        do{
            try imageToSaveAsDatatest.writeToFile(myFilePathtest, options: .DataWritingAtomic)
        } catch {
            print("Error, cannot write to the location \(myFilePath)")
        }

        // Load from Disk! Page 2
        let loadedImageDatatest = NSData(contentsOfFile: myFilePathtest)

        // Check the data is the same
        if loadedImageDatatest == imageToSaveAsDatatest {
            print("✌️")
        }

        // Have a look at the loaded image!
        var bobtest = UIImage(data: loadedImageDatatest!)

        var imagecool = UIImageView()
        imagecool.image = bobtest

        //Page 4

        let imageViewPage4 = uiview3


        // Find the path where to save
        guard let myFilePathPage4 = createMyFilePath(forFileName: "Page4test.png") else {
            print("Cannot generate file path ☹️")
            exit(0)
        }

        // Use this to check in finder where your file is saved
        print(myFilePathtest)

        // Transform the imageView in UIImage to save it
        let imageToSavePage4 = createImage(fromView: imageViewPage4)

        // Get the image as data
        guard let imageToSaveAsDataPage4 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageToSavePage4) else {
            print("Cannot transform image to data ☹️")
            exit(1)
        }

        // Save to Disk!
        do{
            try imageToSaveAsDataPage4.writeToFile(myFilePathPage4, options: .DataWritingAtomic)
        } catch {
            print("Error, cannot write to the location \(myFilePath)")
        }

        // Load from Disk! Page 4
        let loadedImageDataPage4 = NSData(contentsOfFile: myFilePathPage4)

        // Check the data is the same
        if loadedImageDataPage4 == imageToSaveAsDataPage4 {
            print("✌️")
        }

        // Have a look at the loaded image!
        var bobPage4 = UIImage(data: loadedImageDataPage4!)

        var imagepage4 = UIImageView()
        imagepage4.image = bobPage4

         print("Test--2")
```

I get a printout in the console:

[image: This the "crash"]

I have no idea whats going on. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is memory issue, something related to image size maybe you need to review your code and try to resize images . this answer can help you to figure out why you get this error try to check it [communication problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28795166/what-is-communications-error-os-xpc-error-in-xcode-6) . hope it help

Comment: I've located where exactly I'm getting the problem and it's when I try to save Page 2 or 4. I don't know why though. Any ideas?