# Getting Communications not long before crash when running software on older iPad

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8, ios9.3

Thanks for reading my request for help.

Full error text:

```
 Communications error: <OS_xpc_error: <error: 0x398bf654> { count = 1, contents =
"XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x398bf854> { length = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted" }
```

Here's what is going on.  I have my software working on an iPad with XCode 8.3.2 in iOS 10.3.  I have another iPad, an older one, that's running iOS 9.3.  This iPad was the one I was developing on for awhile before I put the software on the newer iPad, and now I'm trying to get the software to work again on the older iPad.  All this to say, the software used to work on the older iPad, though that was awhile ago (with some changes made to the software since then).  This error I'm receiving, happens every time I push a particular button in the software; however the error occurs at different lines within the software so commenting a line out doesn't fix the bug.  I think this might be some kind of version issue, but I think I have the settings correct for running on iOS 9.3.  If someone can point out even just the meaning of the error code (I can't find it online) that would be tremendously helpful.  I don't think my code is relevant, since even though it crashes with the same button push, it doesn't crash in the same line of code.  In fact, it crashes at a different line each time.  Any help would be great.

Sincerely,
Sean

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28795166/what-is-communications-error-os-xpc-error-in-xcode-6

Comment: Okay, that sort of tells me a little bit about the problem, but offers no real solution.  In my case, the error occurs every time I run the software- it isn't intermittent in that sense.

Comment: So… what is your software doing when that error appears? **Be specific.**

Comment: My software is trying to initialize an SKSpriteNode when this error occurs.

Comment: I don't know why that error occurs, but I commented some lines that weren't necessary above the line where the error occurs, and the software didn't crash!  Yay!  The problem was really the crash, and I'm glad it isn't crashing there anymore.